# ionic 4 capacitor storage gets clear when reopen the app in ios

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

Recently I moved from Cordova to capacitor storage API. And **I am having an issue like when we reopen app all stored data gets clear only in IOS but in android its works fine!**

storage.service.ts

```
    import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
    const { Storage } = Plugins;

    public setStoragedata (keyname: string, data: any) {
        
     return new Promise(resolve => {
       Storage.set({key: keyname, value: JSON.stringify(data)})
      .then(result => {resolve(result)})
      .catch(e => resolve(false));
     })
    }

    public getStoragedata (keyname: string) {
       return new Promise(resolve => {
        Storage.get({key: keyname})
         .then(result => { resolve(result.value); })
          .catch(e => resolve(false));
      })
     }
```

Comment: How much data are you storing? Could be capacity issue. `Storage` plugin is mostly meant for smaller data sets.

Comment: I am storing a very small amount of data.